# Profile doesn't match bundle identifier

Tags: ios, xcode

So I'm trying to submit an app to the app store.  This is my first app so I think I jumbled it somewhere.

In iTunesConnect, my BundleID is com.mywebsite.appname

I created a distrubition profile through the Provisioning Portal with the same app ID that I used to create the BundleID in itunesConnect.  When I try to code sign my release build, I see this:

```
AppName (for bundle identifiers 'com.mywebsite.AppName')
profile doesn't match bundle identifier 'mywebsite.AppName'
```

From googling, it looks like that the bundle ID is case sensitive.  I tried creating another app ID in the dev portal as appname, but it didn't seem to matter since now in the dev portal, I have two apps called Appname.  Even though it let me add another app ID, it displays them the same with the first letter as caps, and the rest not.  So what do I need to do in order to get my profile to match the bundle id.  And which bundle id do I need to match, the one on iTunesConnect?

Lastly, I want to make sure that the name of my app underneath the icon on the iPhone doesn't show up in lowercase.  Is that possible?  Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the leading "com." is missing somewhere.

Comment: @Thilo right but I don't know how to add that back somewhere.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This screenshot shows you where in Xcode to set the Bundle Identifier:

[image]

Comment: can we change it in code in any event.Or somehow using infoplist.strings

Comment: @Hercules I doubt it; you cannot make changes to the app bundle at runtime.

Comment: I do not want to change it in xcode code.I am working on jenkins and I want to change it using variable before build.May be xcconfig can do something

Comment: @Hercules In that case you can change it I would have thought.  Try `man PlistBuddy` from the command line.

Comment: this needs updating, the photo no longer matches xcode